# i try to use map view in my flutter app and got some errors

Tags: gradle, flutter, android-mapview

i try to use map view in my flutter project and when i run the app i got some errors :

> - Error running Gradle:
>     ProcessException: Process "E:\flutterProjects\flutter_course\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
>
> Configure project :map_view
>   WARNING: The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for
>   Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1.
>   Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used.
>   To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin
>   now has a default version of the build tools.
>
> FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
>
> - What went wrong:
>     The Android Gradle plugin supports only Kotlin Gradle plugin version 1.2.51 and higher. Project 'android' is using version 1.1.2-4.
> - Try:
>     Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get fullinsights.
> - Get more help at https://help.gradle.org
>
> BUILD FAILED in 15s
>   Command: E:\flutterProjects\flutter_course\android\gradlew.bat >app:properties
>   Please review your Gradle project setup in the android/ folder.

Comment: The error seems to tell you exactly what you need to do. Have you tried removing buildToolsVersion 27.0.3 from your build.gradle file? "The specified Android SDK Build Tools version (27.0.3) is ignored, as it is below the minimum supported version (28.0.3) for Android Gradle Plugin 3.2.1. Android SDK Build Tools 28.0.3 will be used. To suppress this warning, remove "buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'" from your build.gradle file, as each version of the Android Gradle Plugin now has a default version of the build tools."

Comment: i tried to do what he said but still same error